# How do I input (magnitude of) numerical data in CNN/U-net like architectures?

Tags: machine-learning, neural-networks, conv-neural-network

I've been given some (latitudes,longitudes) points with cellular signal strength(float numbers) on those particular points. And I've been given the location, (lat,longs) of cellular towers in a particular area. Also I've been given the terrain data, i.e. the (latitude,longitude) locations of areas where there are buildings, trees, hills etc. that can cause disruption of signals. I can plot all these points on a map(such as OpenStreetMaps).

I have to predict the signal strengths for new areas given all this data(terrain data and tower sites). Basically, the signal strength will depend on the nearby areas(i.e. if they are hills or buildings or trees and so on) and how close a tower is to a particular point.

The problem I'm facing is that how do I account for magnitude of signal strengths on a map? In every tutorial I've read, the input is an image and the magnitude of something is never accounted for(atleast that's what I feel).

Please comment for any more details needed for an answer.

Comment: every value in an image is simply the magnitude of red, blue, or green light captured at that pixel

Comment: So are you suggesting that I add Signal Strength as one more dimension to the pixel of the image? And how would I go about unknown values where data dosen't exist, maybe label them with negative values? Also, will I have to use 3D Convolutions for this?

Comment: Cross-posted: https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/414777/2921, https://cs.stackexchange.com/q/111169/755.  Please [do not post the same question on multiple sites](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/64068).